# What is the difference in function between $("#item").val(); and document.getElementById("item").innerHTML;?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the difference in function between

```
$("#item").val();
```

and

```
document.getElementById("item").innerHTML;
```

?

I used the first call to get the value for a button and the second for the inner content of a div. What is the equivalent jQuery for the second call and why can't the first call be used on a div?

Comment: They do two very different things. What is the difference between an apple and a chair?

Comment: This is RTFM kinda question... Sadly info on JS is scattered, your best resource here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `val()` if the element has no value. It's equivalent to `document.getElementById("item").value`.

`document.getElementById("item").innerHTML` would be equivalent to `$('#item').html()`.

http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for

```
$("#item").html();
```

[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

To compare apples to apples:

```
$("#item").val() === document.getElementById("item").value;
$("#item").html() === document.getElementById("item").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#item").val();`  will get the value attribute of inputs. while innerHTML would get the content(HTML).

use `$("#item").html();` for the jquery version of this

Answer (score 0):

Because val is for getting value for value attribute.Div cant have value attribute. You could get div element text by $(element).text();